# How to use carousel with a vertical thumbnail

Tags: javascript, carousel, e-commerce, product, slick.js

I want to use slickjs carousel for an e-commerce product single page
with a vertical thumbnail and zoom

if you have an idea please help, thanks in advance

[image: example vertical tumbnail]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use css with flexbox and change the `flex-direction: coumn;` on the same container that you are targeting with slick. You might have to change some other properties such as margin and padding to position them properly, but that would be a simple css based solution.